# ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

Does anyone know how to get around this error ? this sql works fine, but for the 'cumulinvoiced' partitioning function. i'm trying to add a cumulative total, but it doesn't seem to work on inline views.

```
SELECT a.mois, a.supid, a.status, COUNT (a.status), 
       SUM (COUNT (a.status) OVER (ORDER BY a.status, a.supid, a.dossier, a.mois)) cumulinvoiced 
from (SELECT TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM') mois, 
             benefit#sup_inv_id supid,
             SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1) status,
             files#fil_secid dossier
        FROM sbbenefit   
       WHERE benefit#sup_inv_id = 30515   
         AND SUBSTR(si_benstatus, 1, 1) = '2'
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM'), benefit#sup_inv_id ,SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1), files#fil_secid) a 
GROUP BY a.mois, a.supid, a.status 
order BY a.supid, a.mois , a.status
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the SQL you are trying that does not work and generates the ORA-30483?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The aggregate `COUNT` should be an argument to the analytic `SUM`, not vice versa:

```
SELECT a.mois, a.supid, a.status, COUNT (a.status), 
       SUM (COUNT (a.status)) OVER (ORDER BY a.status, a.supid, a.dossier, a.mois) cumulinvoiced 
from (SELECT TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM') mois, 
             benefit#sup_inv_id supid,
             SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1) status,
             files#fil_secid dossier
        FROM sbbenefit   
       WHERE benefit#sup_inv_id = 30515   
         AND SUBSTR(si_benstatus, 1, 1) = '2'
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM'), benefit#sup_inv_id ,SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1), files#fil_secid) a 
GROUP BY a.mois, a.supid, a.status 
order BY a.supid, a.mois , a.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytics and grouping don't tend to work together.  If you perform the grouping first then do the analytic query against that result, I think it should work:

```
SELECT mois, supid, status, status_count,
      SUM (status_count OVER (ORDER BY a.status, a.supid, a.dossier, a.mois)) cumulinvoiced 
from
(SELECT  a.mois, a.supid, a.status, COUNT (a.status) status_count
from 
(
SELECT  
 TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM') mois, 
 benefit#sup_inv_id supid,
 SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1) status,
 files#fil_secid dossier
FROM sbbenefit   
WHERE  benefit#sup_inv_id = 30515   
 AND  SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1) = '2'
GROUP BY 
 TO_CHAR (impdate, 'YYYYMM'), 
 benefit#sup_inv_id ,
 SUBSTR (si_benstatus, 1, 1),
 files#fil_secid  
) a 
GROUP BY 
a.mois, a.supid, a.status
) 
order BY 
supid, mois , status
```

Comment: Aggregates and analytics can work together alright, but the aggregates should be arguments to analytics.